# Grouping a datetime by a specific amount of minutes in SQL/Impala

Tags: sql, grouping, impala

I'm using Impala.
My table has separate columns for the date (in the format YYYYMMDD as STRING), hour and minutes (as INT)
For example, I get:

```
date_part    hour_part    minute_part    kpi
20200828     10           10             23
20200828     10           15             64
20200828     10           20             18
```

To combine these columns, I have used the following syntax:

MINUTES_ADD(HOURS_ADD(TO_DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CAST(date_part AS STRING), "yyyyMMdd"))), hour_part), minute_part) AS date_time

Therefore I get:

```
date_time              kpi
2020-08-28 10:10:00    23
2020-08-28 10:15:00    64
2020-08-28 10:20:00    18
```

(please note that my data only is populated each 5 minutes bin)

Now, if I want to calculate a AVG(kpi) over 1 hour, I can do the following GROUP BY:

```
SELECT
    MINUTES_ADD(HOURS_ADD(TO_DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CAST(date_part AS STRING), "yyyyMMdd"))), hour_part), minute_part) AS date_time,
    AVG(kpi)
FROM table
GROUP BY
    DATE_PART('year', date_time),
    DATE_PART('month', date_time),
    DATE_PART('day', date_time),
    DATE_PART('hour', date_time)
```

However, how can I get the query to give an aggregation over 15 minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use arithmetic on minutes:

```
SELECT MINUTES_ADD(HOURS_ADD(TO_DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CAST(date_part AS STRING), "yyyyMMdd"))), hour_part), FLOOR(minute_part / 15)) AS date_time,
    AVG(kpi)
FROM table
GROUP BY date_part, hour_part,
         FLOOR(minute_part / 15)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Impala, but after all the datetime is just the date plus the hours plus the minutes. I would write it like this:

```
SELECT date_part + INTERVAL hour_part HOURS + INTERVAL minute_part MINUTES
```

or

```
SELECT date_part + INTERVAL hour_part * 60 + minute_part MINUTES
```

If I want data per hour that would simply be:

```
SELECT date_part + INTERVAL hour_part HOURS
```

If I want data per quarter of an hour, however, I'll have to evaluate the quarter from the minutes. One could use a `CASE` expression for that, but a simpler way would be integer division:

```
SELECT date_part + INTERVAL hour_part HOURS + INTERVAL (minute_part DIV 15) * 15 MINUTES
```

I don't know whether above syntax works in Impala. In some DBMS it works, in others you'd use `INTERVAL 1 HOUR * hour_part` instead of `INTERVAL hour_part HOUR`, and others may still need a different solution. You have shown a solution with `HOURS_ADD` and `MINUTES_ADD` and you can use these functions of course.

You say you store the date as a string. Why then the cast to string? And why that Unix time thing? This can probably be shortened to `TO_DATE(date_part, "yyyyMMdd")`.

Hence, using above approach with `HOURS_ADD` and `MINUTES_ADD`:

```
SELECT
    MINUTES_ADD(
      HOURS_ADD(
        TO_DATE(date_part, "yyyyMMdd"),
        hour_part),
      (minute_part DIV 15) * 15
    ) AS date_time,
    AVG(kpi)
FROM table
GROUP BY
    MINUTES_ADD(
      HOURS_ADD(
        TO_DATE(date_part, "yyyyMMdd"),
        hour_part),
      (minute_part DIV 15) * 15
    )
ORDER BY date_time;
```