# get count all with groupby timestamp into hourly intervals

Tags: sql, hive, timestamp, impala

I have a hive table that has a timestamp in string format as below,

```
20190516093836, 20190304125015, 20181115101358
```

I want to get row count with an aggregate timestamp into hourly as below

```
date_time               count
-----------------------------
2019:05:16: 00:00:00    23
2019:05:16: 01:00:00    64
```

I followed several [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63630183/grouping-a-datetime-by-a-specific-amount-of-minutes-in-sql-impala) like this but was unable to generate the desired results yet.

This is my final query:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_PART('day', b.date_time) AS date_prt, 
    DATE_PART('hour', b.date_time) AS hour_prt, 
    COUNT(*)   
FROM
    (SELECT 
         from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(`timestamp`, "yyyyMMddHHmmss")) AS date_time 
     FROM table_name
     WHERE from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(`timestamp`, "yyyyMMddHHmmss")) 
           BETWEEN '2018-12-10 07:02:30' AND '2018-12-12 08:02:30') b
GROUP BY
    date_prt, hour_prt
```

I hope for some guidance from you, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract date_time already in required format `'yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00'`. I prefer using regexp_replace:

```
SELECT 
    date_time, 
    COUNT(*) as `count`
FROM
    (SELECT 
         regexp_replace(`timestamp`, '^(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})$','$1-$2-$3 $4:00:00') AS date_time 
     FROM table_name
     WHERE regexp_replace(`timestamp`, '^(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})$','$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6')
           BETWEEN '2018-12-10 07:02:30' AND '2018-12-12 08:02:30') b
GROUP BY
    date_time
```

This will also work:

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20190516093836', "yyyyMMddHHmmss"),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00') AS date_time
```